# Access and change the attributes of <script> tag

Tags: javascript

How can I access and change the attributes of  tag, specially the src?
something like this maybe:

```
document.scripts[i].src
```

of course it does not work!
I intend to alter it this way:

```
document.scripts[i].src += '?ver3'
```

in a loop for all the script on the page.

Comment: This sounds difficult and prone to problems. What is your final goal with this, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Is this to avoid browser caching? if so, I think theres a better solution than this

Comment: You really don't want to mess with the `scr` property from a script tag. Even if you cannot "unload" a script, I guess most browsers will at least transfer/load the script again.

Comment: I need to add a sting to the address so I can load them through a specific proxy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `document.getElementsByTagName('script')` to get all the script elements in the page.

However, any script elements that you find will already have loaded their content, so it will be too late to change the URL that they use to load content.

If you want to alter the URLs, you should use a solution on the server side, so that the URLs are changed when they arrive to the browser.

Comment: anyway to do it client side? I mean what is it supposed to be? Firefox add-on, some proxy server (local)?

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery:

```
jQuery("script").each(function(){
    var old_src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    jQuery(this).attr('src', old_src+'?ver3');
})
```

With good-old JS:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++){
    var old_src = scripts[i].getAttribute('src');
    scripts[i].setAttribute('src', old_src +'?ver3');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. As Guffa said, you can't change content of loaded script. You can change "src" attribute but new script won't load.

Answer (score 0):

Install httpd (Apache) and PHP.
Put into your hosts file (or hosts.txt) this line:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

Write an php script named index.php and put it into server directory (/var/www/html or some like this; depends on configuration).

When you load in web browser `http://example.com` you will be redirected to `127.0.0.1` (your local server) and in PHP this variable `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` will be set to `example.com`.

Get this site (e.g. using cURL), change what you want (using string functions, regex, DOMDocument, SimpleXML, etc.) and send modified content to browser.

That's all. :)